# Split string by "/" and get result in two last words JS

Tags: javascript

I have my url like https://app.asana.com/0/1154029233771298/1161783458298546; I need to get result like 1154029233771298/1161783458298546. Thanks in forward!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you considered `.split()`?

Comment: of course, but I don't know elegant method to get result string

Comment: I can't make assumptions about what has been attempted. May you show that code?

Comment: @evolutionxbox  bro, my question is just about clear method to split string and get two last word in one

Answer (score 1):

You can split the URL string by the `/` character and rejoin the last two elements by the same character:

```
function extractLastWords(url) {
  return url.split('/').slice(-2).join('/')
}

var u = 'https://app.asana.com/0/1154029233771298/1161783458298546'
extractLastWords(u) //    =>    "1154029233771298/1161783458298546"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = str.split("/"); // create array of strings that are separated by '/'
var result = arr[arr.length-2] + "/" + arr[arr.length-1]; // concatenate last 2 indices
```

Or alternatively:

```
var result = str.split("/").slice(-2).join("/");
```

`.split("/")` - create array of strings from delimiter

`.slice(-2)` - get sub-array with only the last 2 elements

`join("/")` - concatenate all strings in array with delimiter